# Load and display DDS (DXT1) file in UWP app

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, win-universal-app, dds-format

I want to load a couple of directdraw surface files specifically DXT1 and display them in my very simple UWP (C# mainly) application.

I have read of DirectXTex but I have no idea if this is the simplest way and if so, how to use it in an UWP application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280986.aspx) has a built-in codec for loading DDS files that use BC1/DXT1 compression. The simplest way to use WIC from a C# UWP is to use [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D). Keep in mind WIC is going to return an uncompressed version of the image, which if that's what you want then you are good-to-go.

> Note that the built-in DDS codec only supports DXT1-DXT5/BC1-BC3 2D image files. It won't load other forms of DDS files. A quick way to check is to look in File Explorer. If the DDS shows up with a thumbnail, it's supported.

It's not clear from your question what it is you are going to do with the loaded data. If you want to use Direct3D from C#, then you should look at something like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/). If you are using Direct2D, Win2D is the way to go.

> For when to use [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) vs. DDSTextureLoader for loading DDS files, see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/). In short: DirectXTex is for tools that need to handle all the various format conversions particularly legacy DDS file formats; DDSTextureLoader in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is intended for 'runtime' use where you can ensure you are loading a DDS file that is already in a supported DXGI format.

Answer (score 1):

Win2D can load and draw directly from BC compressed pixel formats:  http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/BlockCompression.htm